# Getting special folders with a dynamic folder name

Tags: c#

I have an array of folders I'm trying to get the sizes of.

When I get my Documents directory with this method:

```
        string desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

It works great.

But I need to be able to dynamically input the last portion of that - is that possible?

I'd like to be able to call something like:

```
        string desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.VARIABLENAME);
```

Where VARIABLENAME would be a name that I provide (that is an appropriate 'specialfolder' such as 'Favorites' or 'Desktop')

Can this be done?

Comment: Just the the name ideally.... so that the portion of "Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder." would remain the same and I just slap in the variable at the end. I didn't know if that was possible.

Comment: One thing to be careful of, you tagged your question asp.net, stuff like Desktop or Favorites may or may-not exist for the user IIS is running under.

Comment: appreciate that - sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the string form of your enum...

```
var dir = (Environment.SpecialFolder)Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), "Desktop");
string desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(dir);
```

---

Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop.ToString() ==> `Desktop`